# Format for number with floating point

Tags: java, string, floating-point, double, string-formatting

I want to implement format with dynamic floating point for different length of input data in specified length for display. For example `x.xxxx, xx.xxxx, xxx.xx, xxxx.x`.

In other words,

if I have `1.4`, I need `1.4000`.

if `13.4` then I need `13.400`, for every case length should be 5 digits (with no dot).

I'm using

```
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("000000");
```

but can't build a correct pattern. Is there any solution for this?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: what will happen is the number is more than 5 digit - like 123456789 ?

Comment: @Mzf just cut it into 5-signs length. 123456789 = 12345, 123.45677 = 123.45

Comment: so why not transform it to string and take the first 5 char ? if it less then pad with zero at the end  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is not production code. It doesn’t take a leading minus into account, nor very high values of the `noDigits` constant. But I believe you can use it as a starting point. Thanks to Mzf for inspiration.

```
final static int noDigits = 5;

public static String myFormat(double d) {
    if (d < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This does not work with a negative number " + d);
    }
    String asString = String.format(Locale.US, "%f", d);
    int targetLength = noDigits;
    int dotIx = asString.indexOf('.');
    if (dotIx >= 0 && dotIx < noDigits) {
        // include dot in result
        targetLength++;
    }
    if (asString.length() < targetLength) { // too short
        return asString + "0000000000000000000000".substring(asString.length(), targetLength);
    } else if (asString.length() > targetLength) { // too long
        return asString.substring(0, targetLength);
    }
    // correct length
    return asString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. :-) I was afraid that imprecision in the representation of doubles might lead to unexpected results like 1.4 becoming 1.3999, but I haven’t found any examples of it. Maybe the precision of a double and the work of the %f format is good enough for 5 digits.

Comment: If you use Float, it could occurs